# Calling Jquery in speceific wordpress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, header

I have created an online price quote. I don't know coding that much as I'm a small business owner and have to do most things myself. I created a jquery script and i had to keep it in the header as  I dont know how to insert it in the wordpress post.

My question is: How can I make this whole Jquery script only load on http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/ ?

The script is long so i didnt post it but you can view source and it's in the header. It's messy, I know.

The header is used for all the pages and I think its causing some issues with other pages. Please let me know if you have any ideas, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/') == 0) {
   //all jquery code here
}
```

it will restrict the code to any page with `'http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/'` at the begining of the url. This will also account for `'http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/?qsname=qsvalue'` types of urls. But it will also allow for subdirectories `'http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/dir1/dir2/'`.

If you do this:

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/') {
   //jquery code here
}
```

It will restrict to specifically that page.

**EDIT**

On second thought, and even better option would be to create a `.js` document with all of that code. Then do the below in the header to load it dynamically based on the page. This will keep the code from loading at all unless it's needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href == 'http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/') {
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    js.setAttribute("src", "jsfilename.js");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: it still loaded the jquery on my other page. I can still see it if I right click and view source code. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just made a second edit that I think may make it a bit more manageable. How can you tell that the code is loaded on the other pages?

Comment: I can right click and view source and see the code. Because I can see it means its running, correct?

Comment: That is not correct. The actual text will always be apart of the document, and will be parsed by the browser. But when the code runs, the part after the `if` will only run if the condition is true. The edit that I added to my answer will cause the actual text to be in a second document, and will only be pulled in by the browser if the condition is true. (By pulled in, I mean loaded into memory and executed. You will not see the code in the document in view source).

Comment: then, you sir are awesome! Thanks a bunch. I'm going to take the cheap way out and do the first way even though calling a separate JS is a better practice. I'll hire someone when i have more resources! Thanks a bunch!